# 3white wires and one black from the ceiling. How do I wire up a two wire fixture?

Tags: electrical

[image]

Three white wires and one black from the ceiling. How do I wire up a two wire fixture? I've checked with a meter and it seems like the two wires to the far right are hot

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. How was it previously hooked up, and to what? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Before worrying about the fixture think about installing an electrical round metal or plastic box and running the wires through it with the proper connectors.

Comment: How many black wires are there in the orange wire nut? You say there are two hot wires. Is one of them controlled by a wall switch? Did you put the tape on the white wires? If the wiring is NM (aka Romex) there should be equal numbers of black and white wires.

Comment: Is there a box back there? Can you post a close-up shot of where the wires come out?

Answer (score 1):

The black and white wires which have wire-nuts go to the new lamp fixture.

You will be sacrificing 0-10V dimming, emergency lighting, or whatever purpose those other two white wires have.   Note that they are a "line cord" which has been split; this is an illegal wiring method for mains power in a building's structure, hence my suspicion that they are for low voltage.

Also, you should rearrange this so you are wiring into a proper junction box, and if there already is a box, ad a box extension.  This may involve re-positioning the new light slightly.

Answer (score 0):

I am SO sorry, but your question raises more questions before you attempt any work :

At your ceiling shot, I cannot see a box. Any fixture needs one, and mounted solidly.

Not certain what was there prior to this photo. However, I DO see the outline of something round which was there.

I only see one wire to the far right, with tape on it, not certain what you meant by two wires to the far right.

The wires with the orange wire nuts "may" have been what was hooked up to the prior device, but without checking with a voltage checker, any of the wires in the photo could be the "right ones"...

Does / did this circuit have switch that you know of ?

Never do any electrical installation without insuring the power is off to what you are intending on working on.